# Create an assembly in a Web Application project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

In a Web Application project in VS08, how do you create an assembly? E.g. you derive a class based on HtmlGenericControl to form your own div, override the ClientId and UniqueId properties, so as not to get screwed up id's on the client-side, and then you want to use/reference this control in an aspx page.

Please refer to David Lively's answer ([c# control names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632904/c-control-names/1632982#1632982)) regarding the same thing. I have tried his solution but I keep getting "could not load assembly file".

Comment: Could you provide a link to the "David Lively" answer?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean? You create an assembly the same way as with any other kind of project - create a class library.

It sounds like you're talking about creating a control, though. Use File->Add New Project and choose "ASP.NET Control Library".

Comment: I am not trying to create on of these, a System.Web.UI.UserControl. I am trying to inherit from HtmlGenericControl to create a div whose ID won't get all mangled up by asp.net. I must apologize beforehand, but please refer to David Lively's post. I am not sure how to find the post exactly, go to Users, find his name and try to find it by timestamp, that is why I supplied it. Thanks

Comment: Here is the hyperlink to David Lively's answere, I apologize in advance; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632904/c-control-names/1632982#1632982

Comment: I have simply gone; Righ-clicked on Web App project, Add New Item, Added a class and written the following code;Imports System
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.HtmlControls

Public Class MyDiv
    Inherits HtmlGenericControl


    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property ClientID() As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.ID
        End Get
    End Property


    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property UniqueID() As String
        Get
            Return MyBase.ID
        End Get
    End Property

End Class

Comment: If that's working for you, then you should add it as an answer.